# how to copy .bashrc file for several users? on solaris

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, solaris

I used this script

```
#!/bin/bash
X='$( cat etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d: )' #All-users
For X in /export/home/*/.bashrc ; do
  echo "$HOME/.profile'" >> $X
  $X 2>/dev/null
done
source $X
exit 0
```

but I'm faced with error and it is not print what I want

```
./ja1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

./ja1.sh: line 3: `For X in /export/home/*/.bashrc ; do '
```

The main purpose i used this script to print `$HOME/.profile` on `.bashrc` file for all users at once using script on root user. I try one script it work only for one user

```
echo "$HOME/.profile" >> /export/home/test/.bashrc
```

Comment: The `For` on line 3 should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors that will be picked up by running your script through `shellcheck`.

Then break the problem into parts:

- create a function to get a list of user home directories.
- create a function that given a list of user home directories, copies the file.
- combine the above to create your program.

Do this first, then come back if there are still problems.